# Jquery: Hex value not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery

I have a shopping cart that I update using jquery. The user can select any number of currencies to represent the order and when I update the cart total I have the jquery currency amount displayed as hex.

I am wondering if there is a way around this?

My api returns the total + currency symbol:

```
string '&#x24;52.09' (length=11)
```

And my Jquery inserts this into my basket:

```
$('.cart-info-value').html(responseObject.cart_item_total);
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

How do I get this to display correctly?

Comment: Just use `$`. jQuery methods encode their parameters, so your `&#x24;` is encoded as `&amp;#x24;`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis `.html` doesn't (eg. http://jsfiddle.net/0Lxbmgar/) @ OP: can you make a reproducible example? There's not enough data in the question to see what goes wrong

Comment: @blgt You're correct, I was thinking of `text()`.

Comment: Maybe set your API's output headers correctly for use in javascript. I've faced the same problem just a few weeks ago, and I've sent the header to text/javascript in some specific cases. It works like a charm. Also set the character encoding to something suitable like UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you I did some bug testing and I found a .text output... dumb but this helped me find the issue. thanks guys.